# Even Distribution of a Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am building a responsive grid-based website. I have 10 grids, so they are each 10% wide. I have a menu set to the class grid_9, meaning it is 90% wide. Now, my problem is trying to get the li's in the ul to evenly distribute themselves across the width. Next issue, the number of menu items is unknown because this will be converted to a Wordpress theme later.

I would include code but basically I have a div with grid_9 wrapped around a ul with the li items inside, because after that, I have no idea where to go.

Any ideas?

Recap:
Unknown Width of Page
Unknown Number of Items in UL

Comment: try this: li { display:inline-block; }

Comment: @Patrick and may be "text-align: center;".

Comment: yeah, i forgot to mention that, thanks. =)

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS

Option #1

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Option #2

```
text-align:center;
```

Option #3

```
 display:inline-block
```

Without a link to your site or code it's hard to tell but it should be one of those.